# neo4j tool start but no response, always in yellow not turn to green

Tags: neo4j

I use neo4j tool to start Neo4j in windows, But a strange thing is, today, when I open the neo4j shell, I start it , but no response, the status is in yellow and never turn to green, it can't establish neo4j server.

[image]

> It is so terrible for my database!!!!

Does anyone meet this ?

Comment: Can you check if there are any errors in messages.log (in your graph database directory), or console.log (I don't have Windows any more but you might be able to find this file in %APPDATA%/some neo4j directory/logs)

Answer (score 0):

you can always backup your data folder `data/grah.db`, also with the config files in the `conf` folder, than erase the installation and create a brand new one. copy those backups back and start again.

or, to be problem-proof, don't erase the old installation, just create a new one, in case the new one would have more problems to start.